# SSRS Report Numerical Formatting

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, format, case, ssrs-2012

I have a two column table: TYPE and VALUE, with both columns' values being of the type INT.

I must format Value.value in an SSRS paginated report using "+" and "-" to denote the value's sign, and with parenthesis, i.e. "(value)" or without parenthesis as determined by the column TYPE.  If the value of TYPE is > x, then parentheses; else, no parentheses.

I commonly see negative values formatted with parenthesis, i.e. (1,000), but in this case I can't use that standard.

Here's an example of the four solutions I seek, exemplified by the values -1,000 or 1,000, having TYPE > or < x, respectively:

```
(-1,000)
-1,000
(+1,000)
+1,000
```

SSRS reports' user interface seems to allow custom expressions for both VALUE and FORMAT.  In this instance, I'm creating a custom VALUE expression but not a custom expression for FORMAT (it's possible a solution might combine custom expressions using both).

Here's my attempt, which isn't working (object error).

```
=iif(TYPE.value > x AND VALUE.value > 0, "(+"&VALUE.value&")"), 
 iif(TYPE.value > x AND VALUE.value < 0, "(-"&*VALUE.value&")"),
 iif(TYPE.value < x AND VALUE.value < 0, "-"&VALUE.value,
 "+"&VALUE.value)
```

Welcome any guidance.  Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few typo's in your expression, for example you need to reference the `Fields` collection ( `Fields!Value.Value` etc. ) and you have an `*` in there for some reason.

Anyway, there is simpler way to do this.

Don't change the value expression, just change the format expression of the text box.

In the number format string you can specify how positive and negative numbers are displayed so all you really need to determine is if Value > X

I created some sample data with the following dataset query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (X int, Value int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,2),
(3,2),
(-10, -11),
(-2234, -1234)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a table. The first two columns show the actual numbers with NO formatting.

The third column shows the formatted output.

The report design looked like this (note that the 3rd column shows [Value] as I have not made any changes to the value expression

[image]

In the `Format` property of the 3rd cell I used the following expression

```
=IIF(
Fields!Value.Value > Fields!X.Value,
"(+#,0);-#,0",
"+#,0;(-#,0)"
)
```

This simply reads

> "If Value > X then format +ve numbers in parentheses with a + sign,
> and -ve numbers with no parentheses and a minus sign, ELSE, format +ve
> numbers with a plus sign and -ve numbers in parentheses with a -sign"

Which gives the following output.

[image]

Comment: Kind thanks, Alan.  Your approach nailed it - and yes, I did leave blank necessary code (i.e.Fields!) - my mistake.  I found that additional formatting - adding a third segment to turn zero's into dashes - was an added touch.  Here's the end product, with great credit to you.  

```
=iif(Fields!VALUE.value > X, "(#,0);(-#,0);--", "#,0;-#,0;--"
=iif(Fields!VALUE.value > X, "(+#,0);(-#,0);--", "+#,0;-#,0;--" #an added formula to include "+"
```